# The transition matrix from $B$ to $E$ is $P_{B\to E}= \begin{bmatrix} 1&2&1\\1&-1&2\\2&2&3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $E\;\ldots$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am stuck on the assignment and I am not sure how I should do it. Would I be correct in saying that $u_1 = (1;1;2)$, $u_2 = (2;-1;2)$, $u_3 = (1;2;3)$?

> d) Given $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $E=\{e_1=(1;0;0),\,e_2=(0;1;0),\,e_3=(0;0;1)\}$ is standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The transition matrix from $B$ to $E$ is $P_{B\to E}=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1&2&1\\1&-1&2\\2&2&3
> \end{bmatrix}$. Let's define all vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$ of basis $B$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What does "Q" mean for linear algebra? Only over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Q means "Question" probably

Comment: Yes, Q stand for question, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the columns of the matrix $P$ as the coordinates of the basis $B$ in terms of $E$, this is the definition of the transition matrix.
you get:
$u_1 = 1\cdot e_1 + 1\cdot e_2 + 2\cdot e_2$
$u_2 = 2\cdot e_1 + (-1)\cdot e_2 + 2\cdot e_2$
$u_3 = 1\cdot e_1 + 2\cdot e_2 + 3\cdot e_2$

A bit confusing at first but remember that columns of a transition matrix just represents coordinates of one basis in terms of another.